# Customize bullets depending on children in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In the Worg [FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#org1447be9) I read that it is possible to overlay the asterisk * characters for headings.

Is it possible to compute the header overlay (or even the org-ellipsis) depending on whether the heading has a) children and b) text in the body?

source file:

```
* no  child, has text body
  body
* no  child, no  text body
* has child, has text body
  body
** child
* has child, no  text body
** child
```

actual display in buffer when collapsed:

```
* no  child, has text body...
* no  child, no  text body
* has child, has text body...
* has child, no  text body...
```

desired:

```
* no  child, has text body...
* no  child, no  text body
+ has child, has text body...
+ has child, no  text body
```

The functions org-show-children, org-hide-subtree, outline-show-entry, outline-hide-entry look promising to compute it, but I am missing the entry point.